# Can't get the "stem" module to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tor

I installed the `stem` module and did some copy/paste from the tutorials on their official site. None of them worked here.

In fact it doesn't even work when I type "from stem.control import Controller" in the command line. That gets me the following "error code":

```
>>> from stem.control import Controller
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1521, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
from stem.control import Controller
File "C:\Python33\_PROJECTS\stem.py", line 6, in <module>
import build.lib.stem.process
File "C:\Python33\lib\build\lib\stem\__init__.py", line 421, in <module>
import stem.util.enum
ImportError: No module named 'stem.util'; stem is not a package
```

I'm using Python 3 and `stem` is supposed to work with it. Am I missing out something super obvious here?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Tried with "pip install stem". Installation got well but I got error codes when I tried running scripts (also when I typed "from stem.control import Controller" in the command line). I then uninstalled it (with "pip uninstall stem") and tried "python setup.py install" and it went the same - installation OK but error codes when I ran script. :(

Any suggestion?

Comment: Worked fine for me. In case you don't trust `pip uninstall`, you can manually remove the `stem` and `stem...egg-info` directory and file, and run `python3 setup.py install` again. Make sure you're *outside* the stem source directory when trying out the imports on the Python cmdline.

Answer (score 0):

From your traceback, what is this file?

```
File "C:\Python33\_PROJECTS\stem.py"
```

You are probably attempting to import this file, instead of the actual package (The last line of the traceback reveals so much).

Be careful when naming scripts identical to package name: the current working directory is added to the front of `sys.path`, and thus, such a script may get imported instead of the actual package. I assume you actually tried the imports from the `C:\Python33\_PROJECTS\` directory.